# Persistance Unit Error More 2 EntityManagers 1 Persitance Unit?

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-7

Hi im working with Java EE 7. The code got the following structure.

model --> Entity Beans

business --> Service classes for the model (each contains a EntityManager)

presentation --> Named SessionScoped Beans with @EJB on the service

When i tested the program with just 1 service / EntityManager everything works fine but now when i added the second service class i got this error:

```
>

SEVERE:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SEVERE:   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [watchuwantPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class model.Tag] uses a non-entity [class java.lang.String] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field beschreibung].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1950)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1941)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="watchuwantPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>watchuwant</jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

FilmService.java

```
@Stateless
```

public class FilmService {

```
@PersistenceContext(name="watchuwantPU", unitName = "watchuwantPU")
private EntityManager em;

public void add(Film Film){
    em.persist(Film);
}

public List<Film> findAll(){
    return em.createQuery("select f from Film f order by f.id").getResultList();
}
}
```

LizenzPM.java

```
@SessionScoped
@Named

public class LizenzPM implements Serializable{

private String lizenzgeber;
private String lizenztyp;
private String lizenzurl;
private Date erteiltAm;


@EJB
private LizenzService service;
```

Film.java Entity

```
@Entity
public class Film implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String titel;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Tag> tags = new LinkedList<>();
```

Tag.class Entity

```
@Entity
public class Tag implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private String beschreibung;
private Film parent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the persistence unit name is `watchuwantPU`, not `LizenzService`. Check the `@PersistenceContext` annotation.

Comment: Also, please note that, by convention, the persistence configuration is done in a file named `persistence.xml`.

Comment: If have edited my post and insert the new error message. i also have the persistence.xml in it

Comment: Ok, now I see. It looks like you have some errors in the Object-Relational mapping inside one of your entity classes. Could you post the content of class `Tag`? It looks like you're defining a relationship (maybe a `@ManyToOne` annotation) on a `String`-typed field, which is kind of erroneous.